# How to solve this system of equations containing reciprocals?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Suppose I have some numbers...

$p_i = \frac{b_i}{1 + ( l_i+mr_i)}$

where $i\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $p_i, b_i, l_i, m, r_i \in\mathbb{R}$

I want to solve for $m$, such that

$ \sum p_i=x $

where $x\in\mathbb{R}$

Is there an elegant way to do this?

I have tried to use Sympy to solve something similar, but it gives a messy solution:

```
solve( -0.1 + 1/(a0+b0*m) + 1/(a1+b1*m), m)

[0.5*(-a0*b1 - a1*b0 + 10.0*b0 + 10.0*b1 - sqrt(a0**2*b1**2 - 2.0*a0*a1*b0*b1 + 20.0*a0*b0*b1 - 20.0*a0*b1**2 + a1**2*b0**2 - 20.0*a1*b0**2 + 20.0*a1*b0*b1 + 100.0*b0**2 + 200.0*b0*b1 + 100.0*b1**2))/(b0*b1),
```

0.5*(-a0*b1 - a1*b0 + 10.0*b0 + 10.0*b1 + sqrt(a0**2*b1**2 - 2.0*a0*a1*b0*b1 + 20.0*a0*b0*b1 - 20.0*a0*b1**2 + a1**2*b0**2 - 20.0*a1*b0**2 + 20.0*a1*b0*b1 + 100.0*b0**2 + 200.0*b0*b1 + 100.0*b1**2))/(b0*b1)]

EDIT: Correcting

$ \sum o_i=x $

to

$ \sum p_i=x $

Comment: What is $o_i$? Is it order notation? What about $x$?

Comment: I agree with @Bey : under its present form, your question is hard to understand ; are the $o_i$s in fact $p_i$s ? The example you show is amenable, by reduction to a common denominator, to the solution of a quadratic equation recognizable at its form $\dfrac{-b \pm \sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}$

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo. $o_i$ should have been written $p_i$

Comment: x is just a real number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that if you have $n$ terms $p_i$, then you will get at most $n$ solutions. It can be understood

- algebraically: when you reduce the sum of fractions to which you have added $-x$, you get a polynomial of degree $n$ for the numerator, thus having at most $n$ solutions.
- graphically, on the curve of the function. In fact, each denominator is clearly responsible for an asymptote of the corresponding function; as there are $n$ denominators, the curve will possess, in general (unless two denominators induce the same asymptote), $n+1$ ``branches'' of the curve (the first and the last branches having the $m=x$ axis as an horizontal asymptote).

Here is an example, function:

$$y=1/(2 - m) + 3/(6 - 2m) + 1/(2 - 2m) + 1/(m - 4) + 3$$

is represented by the following curve, exhibiting 2 real roots.

An advantage of the graphical representation is that it can be used with a ``sliding'' horizontal line, allowing to see how many solutions there are. In our example, in general, for different values of $x$, one may have $2$, $3$ or even $4$ real solution to the equation.

[image]